# Elasticsearch filter results by count of property whose value is less than a number

Tags: opensearch

I have an index that is structured like

```json
{
  "took": 301,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4270,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 2.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "asset_revision_structured_data",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2931293",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "prediction": {
              "drugs": {
                "document_metadata": {},
                "predictions": {
                  "relevant_drugs": [
                    {
                      "confidence_score": 0.9946682341655051
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to filter the results to return all `hits` where 50% or more `relevant_drugs` have a `confidence_score` < 0.6.

I know that this would give me all hits where there *contains* a `relevant_drugs` entry with `confidence_score` < 0.6:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "doc.prediction.drugs"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "doc.prediction.drugs.predictions.relevant_drugs.confidence_score": {
              "lt": 0.6
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": ["doc.prediction.drugs"]
}
```

but I would like to only return back hits where that clause applies to greater than half the `relevant_drugs`. How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like `relevant_drugs` is nested, but for your use case it probably should. Also can you share documents that better highlight what you're after, i.e. one that would satisfy the condition and another that doesn't?

Comment: An example of a doc that doesn't satisfy it:
"doc": {
            "prediction": {
              "drugs": {
                "document_metadata": {},
                "predictions": {
                  "relevant_drugs": [
                    {
                      "confidence_score": 0.9946682341655051
                    },
                    {
                      "confidence_score": 0.6546682341655051
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
If the confidence scores were both < 0.6, then that would satisfy it

Comment: It seems that you can calculate it at the index time, may I ask the purpose of not pre-processing? Since using aggregate functions while querying is an expensive method even you find a solution it may not be feasible with big amount of documents.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I don't believe `Elasticsearch` has a specific query to do so.
But you can use [Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html). It allow for scripted behaviour in your queries. I also leverage the [RuntimeFields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) to create on the fly a field I can apply a filter to.

## To Reproduce

Here is the data I used to run my tests

```json
POST /71916396/_doc
{
  "relevant_drugs": [
    {
      "confidence_score": 0.9946682341655051
    },
    {
      "confidence_score": 0.8946682341655051
    }
  ]
}

POST /71916396/_doc
{
  "relevant_drugs": [
    {
      "confidence_score": 0.9946682341655051
    },
    {
      "confidence_score": 0.02
    },
    {
      "confidence_score": 0.1
    }
  ]
}

POST /71916396/_doc
{
  "relevant_drugs": [
    {
      "confidence_score": 0.1
    }
  ]
}
```

## To Solve

Below the query, with a runtime field getting the median of all the confidence_score in your documents.
And then filtering for low confidence score.

```json
GET /71916396/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "confidence_median": {
      "type": "double",
      "script": {
        "source": """
        def drugs = params['_source']['relevant_drugs'];
        
        def sorted_drugs = drugs.stream().sorted((d1, d2) -> d1.get('confidence_score').compareTo(d2.get('confidence_score'))).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        def median = -1.0;
        if (sorted_drugs.length % 2 == 0)
        {
          median = ((double)sorted_drugs[sorted_drugs.length/2]['confidence_score'] + (double)sorted_drugs[sorted_drugs.length/2 - 1]['confidence_score'])/2;
        }
        else
        {
          median = (double) sorted_drugs[sorted_drugs.length/2]['confidence_score'];
        }
        
        
        emit(median)
        
        """
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "confidence_median": {
        "lte": 0.6
      }
    }
  }, 
  "size": 10
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution! One problem... we're currently using Opensearch 1.1, which I don't believe has the runtime fields feature. Do you know of an Opensearch equivalent solution?

Comment: Ahh damm ! I only know about `ElasticSearch`. Would you be able to migrate from `opensearch` to `ElasticSearch` XD